# Can Anova F-Value be scaled to a specific range?

Tags: anova

I'm using sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif(X, y) function to compute the ANOVA F-value for a sample. I noticed that the returned F-statistic is not in a specific range, that is, it can take on very large values. This makes it difficult to evaluate how relevant a feature is to the target variable. For example, Pearson Correlation returns a value within the range -1 and 1, so that if I got a value like 0.99 I can conclude that there is high correlation (of course given that p-value is < 0.01). I know that Pearson correlation is the scaled version of covariance, it is found by dividing the covariance by the product of the stds of both variables. In a similar vein, is it possible to scale Anova-F value to a specific range? You might say that for feature selection ranking the variables is enough, it is true, but my aim is not just to make feature selection, but to understand the magnitude of the relationship between the input features and the target variable. An unbounded F-value does not help in this regard.

Comment: Note that hypothesis testing (such as from an ANOVA) serves a very different purpose from the one you are trying to achieve (feature selection/variable importance), so this is not really appropriate.

Comment: @user2974951 are you saying that using ANOVA for feature selection is not appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: Since it is available in sklearn I thought it could be used. Anyway, what else can be used for measuring the dependence between a categorical and a continuous variable?